# Specifying the width of Spring 3 <form:select>

Tags: spring, forms, select, width

How do I specify the with of form:select tag in Spring 3?

I have options list that contains single characters, and by default it is too wide for them.

I have tried 'style="width:5px"' without any change.

Comment: cssStyle? also accept some answers?

Comment: The trick was min-width, not width..

Comment: great, now you can accept some answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
form select {
border:1px solid #006;
background:#FFFFA0;
width:410px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
...
<form:select path="data" style="min-width:400px;"></form:select>
```

min-width worked for me